About prime numbers (Goldbach) and a periodic integer sequence
Let's $2N = P_{2N} + Q_{2N}$, where $P_{2N}$ is the least prime number such that $Q_{2N} = 2N - P_{2N}$ is also a prime number. Now, consider the sequence of numbers defined as $a(N) = (Q_{2N} - 2P_{2N}) \pmod{6}$ for $N=2,3,4,...$, the sequence for $n \ge 3$ is periodic $(3,5,1)$, or, equivalently, $a(N) \equiv a(N+3) \pmod{6}$
Computationally, this proposition appears to hold true; I have verified it up to 400 million. However, I have not been able to establish a formal proof.
PS.: https://github.com/michelyamagishi/Goldbach/blob/main/Periodic_sequence.py

Hint: Primes $ > 3$ are of the form $ 6k + 1, 6k + 5$. Do case analysis. EG For $2N \equiv 2 \pmod{6}$, we either have $(P, Q) \equiv (1, 1), (3, 5) \pmod{6}$, and both yield $ a(N) \equiv 5 \pmod{6}$.

In other words (not exactly same result...), you choose $P_{2N}$ as the least prime number such that etc etc, but you could choose any prime, such that ...  : For example , $100 = 3+97=11+89=13+87$... ; all values $97-2 \times 3$ or $89 -2 \times 11$ or $87-2\times 13$ are equal modulo $6$.

Actually, any odd numbers (p,q) will do: 99 +1, 97+3,.. are all (q-2p) mod 6 =1

So the proposition is:  If p,q are odd numbers and p+q = 2n, then q-2p == 2n+3 (mod 6).

Prof. Carl Pomerance has just provided the answer:
"Well the statement of your theorem presumes that Goldbach has
been proved.  Here's a version that does not make this presumption:
If $2N = p+q$, where $p$, $q$ are primes, then $
\begin{align*}
q-2p&\equiv 3\pmod6\\
\end{align*}
$ when $
\begin{align*}
2N&\equiv 0\pmod6\\
\end{align*}
$,$
\begin{align*}
q-2p&\equiv 5\pmod6\\
\end{align*}
$ when $
\begin{align*}
2N&\equiv 2\pmod6\\
\end{align*}
$ and $
\begin{align*}
q-2p&\equiv 1\pmod6\\
\end{align*}
$ when $
\begin{align*}
2N&\equiv 4\pmod6\\
\end{align*}
$,This holds starting
at $2N = 6$, so that $p$, $q$ are both odd primes.  The proof uses
merely that odd primes are either 1 or 5 mod 6."
